# Is an extension of a discrete absolute value discrete too?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, absolute-value

> Suppose $L/K$ is a finite extension of fields. Suppose $v$
>   is a *non-archimedean* absolute value on $L$ such that the restriction of $v$ on $K$ is
>   non-trivial and discrete. Can we say that $v$ is discrete on $L$?

By "discrete" on $K$, we mean that $v(K^{\times})$ is a discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes: let $\widehat{K}$ be the completion of $K$ with respect to the absolute value $v$. Then by the extension theory for absolute values we know that there exists a field compositum $L\widehat{K}$ within the algebraic closure of $\widehat{K}$, such that

$$v(x)=(v(N(x))^{1/n},$$

where $N$ is the norm function of the finite (!) extension $L\widehat{K}|\widehat{K}$, and $n$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $\widehat{K}$. Since $n$ is bounded from above by $[L\widehat{K}:\widehat{K}]$, the set $v(L^\times)$ is discrete.

Comment: Thank you very much! Really cool, from this answer I just wonder to know where can I find "the extension theory for absolute values"? Could you give me some reference or introduction materials about this, I learn very few about the theory of absolute values. Thank you.

Comment: You could take a look at Lang's Algebra, Chapter XII. However the theory there is written in the language of valuations, that is instead of a non-archimedian absolute value $v$ the map $-\log\circ v$ is considered. Another source is the book Valuation Theory by O. Endler, which sadly is out of print now.

Comment: Forgive me, but somehow I have doubts about this proof (not the statement). Must one not show that the restriction of this extension coincides with the given extension on $L$?